# How to refuse close Dialog when press Esc Key

Tags: front-end, gui-construction, customization, dialog-window

As you can see in the documentation of `CreateDialog`:

> If the dialog contains no `DefaultButton` or `CancelButton`, pressing Enter or Esc will close the dialog without taking any other action.
>
> In dialogs created with `CreateDialog`, pressing Enter is effectively equivalent to clicking the `DefaultButton`, and Esc to clicking the
> `CancelButton`.

For example I have an `InputField`, but when I press Esc key to write any expression, the dialog closes.

I'm trying with the fuction:

```
CreateDialog[Overlay[{DefaultButton[], CancelButton[], InputField[]},{3}, 3]]
```

But it does not work.

How can change this behavior in Dialog?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can overwrite specific `NotebookEventActions` which are responsible for that:

```
CreateDialog[
 Overlay[{DefaultButton[], CancelButton[], InputField[]}, {3}, 3], 
 NotebookEventActions -> {
   "EscapeKeyDown" :> {}, 
   "ReturnKeyDown" :> {},
   PassEventsDown -> True
 }
]
```

`PassEventsDown -> True` allows  `"\[AliasDelimiter]"` to appear in the `InputField` after pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Comment: Ok thank you, the function its ok, but i need write simbols, for example the simbol omega, this its write whit Esc omega Esc in mathematica. I solved the problem with:  CreateDialog[InputField[], 
 NotebookEventActions -> {"WindowClose" :> {}}].

Comment: Sorry the first comment is incomplete. I removed. :)

Comment: @ivan I don't understand, esc+omega+esc is the same as esc+o+esc, at least on my system.

Comment: Yes, its de same. thank you for your healp :)